# jquery ajax result data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble using the return data within my ajax call.  What is the best way to go about this?

I simply send information to checker.jsp.  It computes it.  If the check is good, it responds with a Green.  If it's bad, it responds with a Red.

If I use this within the success:

```
alert(light_color);
```

I get what seems to be the entire web page with the word "Red" 40 lines down.  Because of this the if and elses do not work.  I want to use the result and only the result.  Not the html and everything in it.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated!

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'checker.jsp',
        data: {
            'bank_cnt': bank_cnt
        },
        success: function (result) {
            var light_color = result;
            if (light_color === 'Red') {
              alert('Red');  
            } else if (report === 'Green') {
                alert('Green');
            } else {
                alert('didnt work');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: did u tried writing your contenttype?

Comment: Are you storing the result w/ JSON?

Comment: For a test, try to send a constant string like 'Green' in your `checker.jsp` without any extra process. Do you get this string?

Comment: in the beginning of `success` block, write `alert(result);`, then run, what do u see in this case?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use the result and only the result. Not the html and everything in it.

The 'result' has 'the html and everything in it'. You will need to modify **checker.jsp** to only send 'Red' or 'Green' and also set the content-type in the header of the response to text. You should investigate how to respond to requests in JSON format.

Comment: This is correct. You can send the color result alone and reference that in the url property, or as you said, respond in JSON format. The JSON response is the answer that I chose to provide. Both solutions should work. +1

Answer (score 1):

**1) Store your result w/ JSON:**

```
<%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject"%>
<%
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); 

    //Result stored to JSON on the left.
    //Your result w/ Red or Green stored on the right.
    json.put("result", "result");
%>
```

If you are storing the result w/ JSON, try this (with added `contentType` and `dataType` properties):

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'checker.jsp',
        data: {
            'bank_cnt': bank_cnt
        },
        success: function (json) {
            var light_color = json.result;
            if (light_color === 'Red') {
              alert('Red');  
            } else if (report === 'Green') {
                alert('Green');
            } else {
                alert('didnt work');
            }
        }
    });
```

**Note:** If you don't have the `contentType` declared above, you may need to parse the JSON object:

```
jQuery.parseJSON(json);
```

**2) If you don't want to use JSON:**

Return your result as a separate jsp with just the result text, and reference that page in your `url` property as Alex stated. Grabbing the jsp will return the whole page, so if you just want the result, the result needs to be all that the page consists of.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to **prevent default browser action**, Try those lines and show me what you get.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#your-form-name").submit(function (event) {
        // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser.
        event.preventDefault();
        // request var definition and filling
        bank_cnt= "SOME_DATA"
        // Call your function
        respViaAjax();
}
function respViaAjax() {
    //the response
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8", //Or x-www-form-urlencoded or any other type
        url: "/checker.jsp",
        data: {
            'bank_cnt': bank_cnt
        },
        dataType: 'text',
        timeout: 10000,
        success: function (result) {
            var light_color = result;
            if (light_color === 'Red') {
              alert('Red');  
            } else if (report === 'Green') {
                alert('Green');
            } else {
                alert('didnt work');
            }
        }
        }
    });
});
```

Don't forget to **change var names** if necessary. Hope it work for you..